# Primes Representable as Quadratic Form - Specifically Norm of an Imaginary Quadratic Field with Class # 1

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-number-theory

Could someone point me towards the result that states that a prime is expressible as a norm of an imaginary quadratic field with class number 1 iff $\left(\frac{p}{D}\right)=1$.

Comment: Do you know what the words mean?

Comment: Yeah, why would you ask that?

Comment: I suspect that Will's point is that if you really know the meaning of those terms, then the result follows from the structure of prime ideals of the said field (and the way the rational primes split in there). He is just not blunt enough to phrase it that way.